# bittorent protocol in webassembly

Tags: browser, udp, webassembly, emscripten, bittorrent

Currently I'm investigating if it is possible to use BitTorrent protocol from WebAssembly.
As I know browser itself has limitation and we cannot use pure TCP/UDP Socket, so UDP connections are emulated by WebSockets.
Also I found out that there's Emscripten toolchains for webassembly that allows us to use [Full POSIX Sockets over WebSocket Proxy Server](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/networking.html?highlight=networking)
It says

> Because all API calls are individually proxied, this support can be slow. This support is mostly useful for developing testing infrastructure and debugging.

**Questions**
Can that functionality be used for implementing BitTorrent protocol support in WebAssembly?
Are there more reliable ways for implementing the protocol?
Is it "close to the mind" to have it production ready?

and finally
**Is it even possible**?

Comment: WebSockets does not emulate UDP. You can write an implementation that forwards data to another server that can then send UDP on behalf of your browser application.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing *BitTorrent* in a browser is not possible because [the specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) requires TCP or uTP as transport. [Webtorrent](https://webtorrent.io/) does operate the peer protocol over webrtc, but it's not spec-compliant because it can't talk to clients implementing the torrent spec, existing trackers, the DHT and various [other extensions](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0000.html).

Another issue with webtorrent is that torrents work best when clients operate as long-lived background services so they can do their fair share of uploading and ensure long-term content availability. But websites generally operate in shorter-lived tabs. To my knowledge ServiceWorkers do not help here either because they get suspended when the tabs relying on them get closed, i.e. they don't provide a long-lived background service.

And I suspect that there are other issues/lacking features around filesystem access due to browser security policies. E.g. when migrating from one native client to another you can often tell them to scan the whole filesystem for files matching a torrent that you're reimporting.

So, the general principle is possible, but it falls way short of what a proper bittorrent implementation can do.

Also note that wasm does not have to run a browser, there are webassembly runtimes that aim to provide system-access, e.g. [WASI](https://wasi.dev/) or running [webassembly in nodejs](https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-with-webassembly). With those you can use TCP and UDP and have a proper bittorrent implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I know that it is possible with webassembly in nodejs, but I want to run it in browser, I don't need to seed content from browser, I need only to "download", webrtc is supported with very little torrent libraries, so there'll be too less seeds available, the only way of implementing this I think is to wait for this api https://chromestatus.com/feature/6398297361088512

Comment: @MeruzhanHovhannisyan I need only to "download" - bittorrent is a p2p protocol, the *peer* aspect is important. If you want to download something someone else has to upload it. by symmetry it means if you don't want to seed, who will?

Comment: "I think is to wait for this api"  That won't be good enough for a full featured BitTorrent client.  It will never support listening for TCP connections, and the UDP support is similarly limited.